# How to model a cylindrical extrusion that looks similar to an octagonal prism?

Tags: modeling, extrude

How do I model this cylindrical extrusion with circular base?

[image]

I first tried starting from a cylinder, although, when it comes to give thickness (by converting it to Curve/Geometry/Depth) the structure deforms and appears uneven.

I made a second endeavor by starting from a duplicated Circle, and extruding the circular vertices to match them with the other sides and finally applying a Solidify modifier but I got the following results, which are far from the object:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3):

Your desired mesh can easily be modeled using T-Joints. Luckily you don't have to model these because they are readily available within the built-in addon [`Add Mesh: Extra Objects`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html). Enable it under menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* and search for "Extra Objects".

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to ensure the 3D Cursor is at the World Origin, and add one T-Joint object via menu *Add > Mesh > Pipe Joints > Pipe T-Joint*. Customize the properties of your object such as the radius within the [`Adjust Last Operation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#bpy-ops-screen-redo-last) popup that appears in the lower left corner. Rotate the joint on the Y-Axis by 90 degrees and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Apply Rotation*. Then add a Circle curve via menu *Add > Curve > Circle*.

[image]

Select the pipe and add an [`Array Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) and set the *Count* to 8.

[image]

Then add a [`Curve Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) and set the curve you added as the *Curve Object*.

[image]

Now to distribute the 8 joints in an even manner, press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to go into top view, and adjust the circles scale and/or the Array Modifier's *Factor X* (or *Factor Y* depending on the orientation of your object) property value.

[image]

Select the pipe objects and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> click one end of the pipe object to [`Select Edge Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) and press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and press <kbd>X</kbd> to extrude it along the X-Axis. Make sure the extruded edge aligns perfectly to where the end of the neighboring pipe's edge used to be aligned at. Then set the Factor X back to 1.0 so they stick side to side. You may need to frequently jump back and forth into *Object/Edit Mode* to view the result if the ends perfectly align on the curve. Also make sure the Array Modifier's *Merge* property is ticked.

[image]

Add some [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) to the extended region to add more geometry so it can bend more smoothly.

[image]

Once you're happy with the output you can convert the entire object to a single mesh by either applying all the modifiers or right clicking the object and selecting *Convert To > Mesh*. Select all the Edge Loops of the upper pipe opening and extrude it along the Z-Axis with <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected* to bring up the 3D Cursor. Now <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode* and right click the pipes and select *Set Origin > Origin To 3D Cursor*.

[image]

The previous 2 steps are needed for the [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) you will add now, and mirror it along the Z-Axis. Convert to mesh and <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* and increase the *Merge Distance* to maybe 0.001 or 0.005 to make sure all vertices have been merged. Then you can optionally add a [`Subdivision Surface Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) to make it nice smooth with levels 2 or 3.

[image]